# Clearing temp items stored by Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

We use this script to try and get information from some of our servers. Issue that I have is the script somehow "saves" the last server IP, so when the next server in the list is unreachable we still get a "success" response from the previous IP. I have tried using the `Clear-Item variable: command` after every test but it doesn't seem to release the value.

```
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$filename_SRM = 'C:\Scripts\' + $enddate + '_SRM_Scan.csv'

$compArray = get-content C:\Scripts\Servers.txt 
foreach($strComputer in $compArray)
{

  $ErrorActionPreference = “SilentlyContinue”
  $ping = new-object system.net.networkinformation.ping
  $ping.send(“$strComputer”) | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'Address'}
  $pingreturns = $ping.send(“$strComputer”).Status

  $socket = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
  $port = 135  #445
  $socket.Connect($strComputer, $port)

  $Network = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $strComputer | `
                    Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled -match "True"} | `
                    Select-Object -property DNSHostName,@{N="DNSServerSearchOrder";
                                                        E={"$($_.DNSServerSearchOrder)"}},
                                                        @{N='IPAddress';E={$_.IPAddress}}

  $IP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(“$strComputer”)

  if ($socket.Connected) 
    { 
     $Netlogon = Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $strComputer | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq 'Netlogon'}
     if ($Netlogon) {

         $OS  = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $strComputer
         $services =  Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Service -ComputerName $strComputer 
         "$strComputer ; $pingreturns ; connected ; $($OS.CSName) ; $($Network.IPAddress) "

       }else{ 
                "$strComputer ; $pingreturns ; WMI Unavailable ;  ; $IP"
            }
         }
if (!$socket.Connected)
   {
        echo "$strComputer ; $pingreturns ; Unable to connect ;  ; $IP"
   }

   $socket.Close()
 }
```

Comment: This worked fine when I ran it.

Comment: Add a line `$Network = $null` before the line `$Network = Get-WMIObject ...`.

Comment: What variable are you trying to clear?  I don't see `Clear-Item` in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Clear-Item <variable name>`, try `Remove-Variable <variable name>` or alternatively you could use the syntax `$variable = $null`. Either should work fine.